# how to run a macro while clicking on a value in slicer in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Slicer in my excel with the following 2 values

Add Customer
Add Vendor

I want to open 2 different forms when click on those value. Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can call different forms on slicer clicks, check the below code. Hope it suits your requirement and if not you can use to change as per your requirement.

On Writing your code in `Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate` event, on each slicer click this event will get called.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

If ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Region").SlicerItems("East").Selected = True Then
UserForm1.Show
ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Region").SlicerItems("West").Selected = True Then
UserForm2.Show
End If

End Sub
```

Where,
**Slicer_Region = "Name to use in formulas"**

You can get this name by right click on slicer and click slicer settings. and find the name to use in formula.

**East or West = "Names of slicers"**

For which you want to call different forms.

Comment: I have done it but it didnot work...I suddenly found that the Slicer I made is calling the table so put the code in Private Sub Worksheet_TableUpdate butstill it didn't work

Comment: please help me am really clueless why the results r not coming

Comment: Where are your slicers? I only see 'Add Vendor' and 'Add Customer' buttons.

Comment: please see now that link...the slicer and the table is there only

Comment: `PivotTableUpdate` is not raised when clicking on a slicer or maybe it's because I'm using a PivotChart. I'm trying to find an event that is. Any ideas?

Comment: @MichaelZ.  did you ever get an answer to that question?

Comment: This only works for Pivot table slicers, it does not work for Table slicers directly.

Answer (score 1):

The solution works BUT THE CODE MUST BE in the code module of the worksheet with the pivot table

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

It does not work on main slicer, however if you select any particular item it works. In that case it is better to set the macro on the slicer itselft. You just need to click on slicer and it will be run automatically.