# Auto run macro when clicking one of the options from the slicer in excel

Tags: excel, vba

So I have looked at various questions similar to this but they don't seem to work or are unanswered:
[Run macro when slicer change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53418302/run-macro-when-slicer-change)
[how to run a macro while clicking on a value in slicer in excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998731/how-to-run-a-macro-while-clicking-on-a-value-in-slicer-in-excel-vba)

My Question:
When i click one of the options in the slicer i want it to automatically run one of the macros but it doesn't work, when i run it manually it works, but clicking on the slicer's option doesn't

```
Sub updateFoodSlicer()
  With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicker_TABLE_StackChart")
    .SlicerItems("food").Selected = True
    .SlicerItems("fruit").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("drink").Selected = False
  End With
  With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(Foods_StackChart").PivotFields("FOODS")
    .PivotItems(">0").Visible = False
    .PivotItems(">2").Visible = False
    .PivotItems(">4").Visible = False
    .PivotItems(">6").Visible = True
    .PivotItems(">8").Visible = True
  End With
End Sub
```

Thats my macro, when i click run it works, but i want it so that when i click the option "food" from the slicer i want it to make columns >6, and >8 visible only

By checking out those above stackoverflow question I realized you need an event so I added that, but still it doesn't work:

```
Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
  If ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicker_TABLE_StackChart").SlicerItems("food").Selected = True Then
    Call updateFoodSlicer()
  End If
End Sub
----------------------------

Sub updateFoodSlicer()
  With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicker_TABLE_StackChart")
    .SlicerItems("food").Selected = True
    .SlicerItems("fruit").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("drink").Selected = False
  End With
  With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(Foods_StackChart").PivotFields("FOODS")
    .PivotItems(">0").Visible = False
    .PivotItems(">2").Visible = False
    .PivotItems(">4").Visible = False
    .PivotItems(">6").Visible = True
    .PivotItems(">8").Visible = True
  End With
End Sub
```

EDIT:
Follow up, so I added into the Sheets tab so the macro would run, but now I get the error: method visible of object pivotitem failed
I have tried various solution from online, yet none seem to work

Comment: What module is the event code in? A sheet code module?

Comment: Under the excel it's in a folder called modules, and under module5

Comment: That's your problem. It belongs in the sheet code module.

Comment: how do i add it to sheet code module?

Comment: Right-click the sheet containing the pivot table, and select "view code."

Comment: don't see that option...

Comment: That would be the sheet tab.... otherwise you can just double click the sheet code module, which is under "Microsoft Excel objects" in the project window.... https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGhni.png