# Update a cell value with the value of a selected item of a slicer - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

What I'm trying do is to click/select an item in a slicer, get its value and update a cell with it.

I did some search online and managed to come up with the code below, It partially works but the problem is that it needs to be run (I'd like something that is listening to on "change") to see any update and I feel like that there maybe a more direct and simple approach to it.

```
Sub update_cell()
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim a As Range
    
    Set a = shTestPV.Range("E4")

    For Each x In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Staff_Name").SlicerItems
        If x.Selected = True Then
            a = x.Value
        End If
    Next x

End sub
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998731/how-to-run-a-macro-while-clicking-on-a-value-in-slicer-in-excel-vba

Comment: If you type `vba slicer click event site:stackoverflow.com` in google, you will see so many threads